# Looking for a design pattern for Distributed Programming in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, distributed

All I could find googling is pretty old stuff (2003 - 2005) and was mainly about `.NET Remoting`.

What is the most up to date, design pattern / practice, for building distributed computational systems in .NET 4?

**Update:**

Thanks all for the advice. To summarize, WCF, Windows Azure, and CQRS, have been suggested. I'm looking into all three to see what will best suit my needs. Seems like WCF is the easiest method, and also one I'm partly familiar with.

Maybe someone could share a good resource (link, book) on implementing a WCF solution for distributed computational systems in .NET 4?

Comment: Look at WCF - that's what's replaced .NET remoting.

Comment: If your looking for the most up-to-date, that would be cloud. Azure supports .Net 4.0 but others like AWS are only upto .Net 2.0 http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/faqs/#11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [CQRS](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/) And [Distributed Domain Driven Design](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs)

More details at:

- [CQRS Starting Page](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/)